# How to generate E-mail not Email in elsarticle.cls

Tags: formatting, front-matter, elsarticle

I am using `elsarticle.cls` to typeset the paper. The journal requires "E-mail" not "Email". But `elsarticle` automatically gives "Email". I wonder how to correct it?

I am using the following commands:

```
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}}
 \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
 \tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is
    longer than the first one and with an intention to fill
    in up more than one line while formatting.}

 \author[rvt]{C.V.~Radhakrishnan\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}}
 \ead{cvr@river-valley.com}

 \author[rvt,focal]{K.~Bazargan\fnref{fn2}}
 \ead{kaveh@river-valley.com}
```

Comment: I'd be wary of altering the official submission class, even if you feel that the output is not quite 'correct' here. Usually I would leave this to the editorial office to worry about.

Comment: I agree with @JosephWright: if the journal requires you to use some specific document class, it's because they want you to use the commands available therein. The version they will use for the final typesetting will probably give a different output (eg. use the journal's font, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

The word "Email" is hard-coded in the definition of `\printFirstPageNotes` so you will have to redefine it (or to patch it using, for example etoolbox). Here's the redefinition:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\printFirstPageNotes{%
  \iflongmktitle
   \let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi
  \ifx\@tnotes\@empty\else\@tnotes\fi
  \ifx\@nonumnotes\@empty\else\@nonumnotes\fi
  \ifx\@cornotes\@empty\else\@cornotes\fi
  \ifx\@elseads\@empty\relax\else
   \let\thefootnote\relax
   \footnotetext{\ifnum\theead=1\relax
      \textit{E-mail address:\space}\else
      \textit{E-mail addresses:\space}\fi
     \@elseads}\fi
  \ifx\@elsuads\@empty\relax\else
   \let\thefootnote\relax
   \footnotetext{\textit{URL:\space}%
     \@elsuads}\fi
  \ifx\@fnotes\@empty\else\@fnotes\fi
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn
   \let\columnwidth=\Columnwidth\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}} \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.} \tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is longer than the first one and with an intention to fill in up more than one line while formatting.}

\author[rvt]{C.V.~Radhakrishnan\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}} \ead{cvr@river-valley.com}

\author[rvt,focal]{K.~Bazargan\fnref{fn2}} \ead{kaveh@river-valley.com}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

And an image of the relevant part:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using Gonzalo's suggestion, here's an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}% http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\printFirstPageNotes}% <cmd>
  {Email}% <search>
  {E-mail}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\printFirstPageNotes}% <cmd>
  {Email}% <search>
  {E-mail}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}} \tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.} \tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is longer than the first one and with an intention to fill in up more than one line while formatting.}

\author[rvt]{C.V.~Radhakrishnan\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn1}} \ead{cvr@river-valley.com}

\author[rvt,focal]{K.~Bazargan\fnref{fn2}} \ead{kaveh@river-valley.com}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

The dual patch of `\printFirstPageNotes` replaces successive usages of `Email` with `E-mail`, one at a time.